# NodeJS passing variable to already defined callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the following code:

```
    if(connections.hasOwnProperty(id)){
        console.log('client '+id+' is connected. querying redis.');
        id = id;
        redisClientActor.lrange("NOTIFICATIONS_"+id, 0, 0, function(err, reply) {
            if(reply !== null && reply !== undefined){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(connections)));
                connections[id].sendUTF(reply);
                console.log('Forwarded notification to client '+id);
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }else{
        console.log('Received notification, but client '+id+' not connected.')
    }
```

it's part of a very basic notification server written in NodeJS. It's using the *redis* npm package. 
Because of the asynchronous nature of Node I understand why the code is unable to work currently (**id** is out-of-scope which leads to **sendUTF** failing which leads to the script crashing).

If *lrange* was a self-defined function I'd simply add a third parameter here and be done with it. But since it isn't I struggle to find the solution as to how access "id" inside of the **lrange** callback (l5 and following)

I'd be very grateful for a quick hint in the right direction.

Comment: actually id is not out of scope, it should be there. Are you using this snippet within a loop that iterates through a series of values which are assigned to the variable "id"? At the end of the loop the value of id would be fixed to the last value of the iteration. Every callback would then see that last value of id.

Comment: Where does id come from? Shouldn't the check `if(connections.hasOwnProperty(id)) { ... }` happen inside the callback to lrange? Also, what is the purpose of the line `id = id;` ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are iterating through a loop that alters the value of "id", the callbacks would all see the last value of "id" which was assigned to it during the last iteration.

In that case you need to capture the value of id with a closure:

```
var produceClosureForId = function(id){
    return function(err, reply) {
        if(reply !== null && reply !== undefined){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(connections)));
            connections[id].sendUTF(reply);
            console.log('Forwarded notification to client '+id);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
}
redisClientActor.lrange("NOTIFICATIONS_"+id, 0, 0, produceClosureForId(id) );
```